# Avoid re-loading UITableView data

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3

I have a problem where a table shows a long list of drills that I want to remain at their current scroll position when user navigates away and then returns.

In my view controller, I have code that loads the data for a UITableView whenever the view appears by calling `getDrillList(optimize: true)` which stores the data in a property called `drillListArray`.

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    getDrillList(optimize: true)
}
```

Here is the code that loads the data

```
private func getDrillList(optimize: Bool = false)
{
    // MAKE API CALL, THE ARRAY IS POPULATED IN THE COMPLETE HANDLER

    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    SharedNetworkConnection.apiGetDrillList(apiToken: appDelegate.apiToken, limit: (optimize ? 13 : 0), completionHandler: { data, response, error in
        guard let data = data, error == nil else {                                                 // check for fundamental networking error
            print("error=\(error)")
            return
        }

        if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {           // check for http errors
            // 403 on no token
            print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
            print("response = \(response)")

            SharedNetworkConnection.apiLoginWithStoredCredentials(completionHandler: { data, response, error in
                let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
                let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: [])
                if let dictionary = json as? [String: Any] {
                    if let apiToken = dictionary["token"] as? (String) {
                        appDelegate.apiToken = apiToken
                        self.getDrillList()
                    }
                }
            })
            return
        }

        self.drillListParser = DrillListParser(jsonString: String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!)
        self.drillListArray = (self.drillListParser?.getDrillListArray())!

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.drillTableView.reloadData()
        }

        if optimize {
            self.getDrillList()
        }
    })
}
```

Two questions

First, if user is shown a segue to another view controller and then returns via `Back`, how can I check if the data is already loaded to avoid loading it a second time? Is it safe to check if the array is empty?

Second, are there any reprocussions I should be aware of with this approach?

Comment: Why the immediate downvote? Please help me revise my question.

Comment: I didn't down vote, but most probably due to the lack of information in your question. You show a piece of code that on its own means nothing and expect people to be able to help without knowing what you're actually doing. Please provide a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: put getDrillList in ViewWillAppear. will resolve issue.

Comment: @Dávid Pásztor thank you, I have added the method call. I wish they would have given me a chance to edit before down-voting. Seems unfair.

Comment: Don't use appdelegate to store your value use you custom singleton class to handle all the value to stored

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `getDrillList(optimize: true)` in `viewDidLoad()` and it will calls once in lifecycle or you can put a check that checks if already loaded a data or not via a boolean flag.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this.